# Prevent UICollectionView subview scrolling

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, subview, sticky-footer

I am working with `UICollectionView`. Never worked with
 this before. So,I am facing lots of issues. One is am trying to add
 `UIView` as subview on `UICollectionView` ,for the purpose of showing
 `UIView` as Pop-Up view on tap of `UICollectionViewCell`. I am able to add
 subview to `collectionView`. But problem is that when I scroll
 `UICollectionView`, the subview also scrolls with it. It want `UIView` to
 stick at bottom of `UICollectionView`.It should not scroll with
`UICollectionView`. It should be always visible on bottom of view. I
 tried to add `UIView` as footer but didn't worked.

Here is my code for
 footerView

```
- (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"add footer view ");
    UICollectionReusableView *reusableview = nil;

    if (kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter) {
        UICollectionReusableView *footerview = [collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter withReuseIdentifier:UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter forIndexPath:indexPath];
        [footerview addSubview:popupView];

        reusableview = footerview;
    }

    return reusableview;
}
-(CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout referenceSizeForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return CGSizeMake(dotsCollectionView.frame.size.width, 120);
}
```

Please suggest me if there's any other way to do this. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: The UIView should not be a subview of the UICollectionView. It should be the siblings to the UICollectionView which will take bottom half of the parent view. In the case you want the UIView to be visible only when user selected a cell, you can play around with the height constraint (provided you added it) of the UIView. Set the height constraint constant to the value you want when user selected a cell and set it to 0 when you want it to be hidden.

Comment: It will be better if you add some images with this post for better understanding :)

Comment: @RicetongTan that should be an answer not a comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UIView should not be a subview of the UICollectionView. It should be the siblings to the UICollectionView which will take bottom half of the parent view. In the case you want the UIView to be visible only when user selected a cell, you can play around with the height constraint (provided you added it) of the UIView. Set the height constraint constant to the value you want when user selected a cell and set it to 0 when you want it to be hidden.

Comment: Thanks @Ricetong, You mean I should add UIView as subview of UIViewController. Well, Idea worked. :-)